# Guardar parte de um texto em uma variavel Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Possuo o seguinte texto:

```
Criado por Comprador em 14/05/2015 - 16:18
```

Gostaria de guardar em uma variável somente a parte `14/05/2015 - 16:18`

Alguem poderia me dar uma luz de como fazer no selenium IDE ?

Answer (score 2):

Tem dois links que podem te ajudar, da uma olhada neles:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537620/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-in-selenium-ide

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981345/selenium-split-date-string-working-example

Comment: Maicon...pelo q entendi nesses exemplos...ele separa uma parte de cada texto..em 2 variaveis...mas eu gostaria de colocar o texto "14/05/2015 - 16:18" dentro de uma unica variavel....

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é adicionar um limitador nesta string por exemplo um - ou | e no código faz o seguinte:

```
store  | Criado por Comprador em | 14/05/2015 - 16:18 | string
store  | 0 | delimiter1
store  | javascript{storedVars['test'].split('|')[storedVars['delimiter1']]} | output
echo   | ${output}
```

E com isso você pega o array que vai reotrnar duas posições e usa apenas a segunda que vai conter a data e a hora.